# Get the context of "this" when using the rxjs5 operator fromEvent?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, addeventlistener, dom-events

How do I get the `this` context when using [`fromEvent`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts) observable?

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    var top = this.scrollY;
   console.log(top)
}, false);
```

But how do I get it when I do fromEvent?

```
 Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
          .subscribe((event) => {
            console.log(this.scrollY);
          });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler) :

> the value of this inside the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the currentTarget property of the event argument that is passed to the handler

So you could just do `event.currentTarget.scrollY`.

Comment: It's not the same. It can point to the same element in some cases but not always.

Comment: well, `.target` seems like a better candidate for scroll delegation anyway, see the example code at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target  ;)

Comment: I'm answering op question which is : "How do I get the this context ?".
And I don't think there is a *better one* they just serve different purpose.